# What is difference between win32com and pywin32?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I know microsoft word document object mode and want to use python as development language what is difference between win32com and pywin32. I tried but could not find answer. Please guide me what to use for python 3.X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

win32com is a "Component Object Model" part of pywin32.

look here for example: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html#Using

pywin32 works with python3.

Comment: pywin32 doesn't works with python3 after installing from pip. working on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238403/import-win32api-error-in-python-2-6/35272621#35272621

Comment: well, python support for windows as always... unstable (