# i am trying to convert text to speech using pyttsx3 in python. but i am getting the error maybe on driverName

Tags: winapi, text-to-speech, pyttsx, python-3.8

i am trying to convert text to speech using pyttsx3 in python. but i am getting the error maybe on driverName.

Here is my code

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

## Here is the Output which gives error.

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
============ RESTART: D:/abhi/My Program/text-to-speech(pyttsx3).py ============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/abhi/My Program/text-to-speech(pyttsx3).py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is no problem.

It can run successfully on my Windows 10, my python version is 3.7.3.

**ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.**

Your win32api module does not seem to be installed correctly, please use `pip uninstall pywin32` to uninstall and use `pip install pywin32` to install again.

You can also refer other methods in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238403/import-win32api-error-in-python-2-6) to solve it.

For `KeyError: None`, you can refer [Python KeyError Exceptions and How to Handle Them](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/) to do some error handling.

Finally, please follow this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-text-to-speech-pyttsx-module/) to convert text to speech.

Answer (score 0):

I sloved my own problem. 
Firstly! I uninstalled Python-3.8 from control panel and installed Python-3.7.2(and added to path during installation).

Secondly,Upgraded setuptool using cmd -> `pip install --upgrade setuptools`.
after that I installed SpeechRecognition, pyttsx3

and after that I also installed
**PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl** using whl file(because pyaudio is necessary to run this program).

Link to download whl file-> [Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) .

Now, This program works.