# about ssl certification error , I wanted to do web scraping but getting an error

Tags: python, html, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying this

```
import requests 
import bs4
import OpenSSL

ctx = ssl.create_default_context() ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning",verify=False)



soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

title = soup.select('.mw-headline')

print(title)
```

But Getting this error

> "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Also, you should use `res.content` instead of `res.text`.

Comment: Looks like a similar problem has been solved previously:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238403/import-win32api-error-in-python-2-6

Comment: This would be easier to parse if you walked us through your process and also, as above reviewer mentioned, show the full error.

Comment: this is the full error : File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.